# How to setup remote debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017. On a remote machine, there is Visual Studio 2012. There I start up msvsmon.exe as administrator, and in the "Tools" menu, I set "No authentication", "Allow any user to debug" (in order to be really sure that I'm not blocked because of permission issues).

On my local PC, I try to setup a debugging session, as follows:

- Connection Type:   Remote (no authentication)
- Connection Target: Find => MachineName: "<_remote_machine>"

A `ping` request to "<_remote_machine>" is successful.

However now connections are found, and in the msvsmon.exe debugging monitor, no messages are seen.

What can cause this and how can I solve it?

P.s. I know that there might be mismatches between the 2012 and 2017 versions, but in that case I expect an error message to be shown in the debugging monitor, but as I said there is nothing there.

Comment: If there is version mismatch the debugging monitor will not show any message. You may also check if port numbers on both sides are the same. Nevertheless it should not be hard to find the "Remote debugger" directory in the VS 2017 repository and copy it to the remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Jszpilewski, simply copying the "Remote Debugger" directory to the remote machine and launching msvsmon.exe from there is the start of the answer.

Following point: once the remote debugger is started, it says something like "Msvsmon started a new server named `'<Machine_Name:Port>'`.

On the local machine you just need to copy/paste this into the "Connection Target" box => Don't try to use the "Find" button, it's a waste of time.